# Dynamic Sitemap Generation

Tags: content-management-system, xml-sitemap

I'm currently using a CMS solution that does not generate any type of Sitemap for use with Google/Bing/Yahoo!/etc.  I've requested it for 4 years now but they do not show any interest in adding it any time soon.

With that being said, I'm trying to find a way to create a sitemap for 1) all of our pages over 5,000; 2) all of our images; and 3) all of our documents.

Can anyone help me with this?  I know my way around PHP and would like to code this up that way but I don't know where to start with crawling my site to generate the links needed. I tried https://github.com/jdevalk/XML-Sitemap-PHP-Script but had no luck as it only returned the 5 pages in the root and none of the child pages inside folders like it was suppose to.  It also showed our last modification date as 1970 which is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Bing XML Sitemap Plugin?

> Blockquote The Bing XML Sitemap Plugin is an open source server-side technology that takes care of generating XML Sitemaps compliant with sitemaps.org for websites running on Internet Information Services (IIS) for Windows® Server as well as Apache HTTP Server.

[Bing XML Sitemap Plugin](https://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/bing-xml-sitemap-plugin-f50bebf5)